# Update Codename One Project to JDK 8 Results In Compilation Error

Tags: java, ant, java-8, codenameone

I’ve updated my project to JDK 8.

This went fine for IOS but when building for Android the following error occurs.

> BUILD FAILED
>
> /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:871: Can't read [/tmp/build1790297227904368708xxx/Main/libs/userClasses.jar] (Can't process class [generated/StateMachineBase.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you set the `java.version=8` build hint in the project properties.